# Cell in Devexpress Treelist is set to editable yet it won't let me edit

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, devexpress

I am using a DevExpress (10.2) Treelist in my VB.Net project in Visual Studio 2008. I currently have a treelist with `TreeList.OptionsBehavior.Editable = True`. I have two columns were the first one is `AllowEdit = False`. The second column I am setting the `AllowEdit` and `ReadOnly` dynamically though the action `FocusedNodeChanged`.

Within the `FocusedNodeChange` subroutine I check if a specific value is in the row and if so I set it to be editable or non-editable. I am setting it to be editable with:

```
treeList.Columns("field_name").OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = False
treeList.Columns("field_name").OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = True
```

and setting it to readonly with:

```
treeList.Columns("field_name").OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = True
treeList.Columns("field_name").OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = False
```

This works to a degree. Right now if I go in the editable cell in the treelist the cursor appears and blinks so I know it is editable and if I go in the cell when the un-editable row is focused the cursor doesn't blink.

However even though the cursor blinks I am unable to type. When I click on keys (numbers and letters) on the keyboard nothing is written.

**SOLVED**

Simple solution. The stored procedure I was using to fetch the data into the table didn't contain the field for the particular column I was trying to make editable and not editable. This was because it was a new value that was insert/updated differently than normal. To fix this I fetched null and/or 0 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are using is not quite correct.  The best solution is to handle the TreeList's [ShowingEditor](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_ShowingEditortopic) event and set the e.Cancel parameter accordingly.  To determine the current cell, use the TreeList's FocusedColumn and FocusedNode properties.

Comment: I removed FocusedNodeChange and did what you said in the ShowingEditor event and I have the same problem. In the rows I can edit I see the blinking cursor and can't type. In the row I don't want to edit I can't type and don't see the blinking cursor.

Comment: Handle the ShowingEditor event and control the cell's editing by the e.Cancel parameter.  You should not change the column's ReadOnly and AllowEdit properties.  This should work.